# Why might mySQL index cardinality change from >0 to null?

Tags: mysql, indexing, cardinality

I'm running mySQL 5.6 on Centos, and having performance problems.  There were a few false starts at trying to set the cardinality of the indexes of an empty table correctly. But once this was done and the indexes of my empty tables were set correctly (to 0, rather than to NULL), I started up a job to populate the tables.

I checked periodically and saw the cardinalities steadily rising.  Then I started another job, and watched the numbers continue to grow.  Finally, I started two jobs concurrently (and I should mention, these jobs talk to a server process that serializes concurrent requests through a single connection to mySQL).  Almost immediately I saw cardinalities start becoming NULL.

There's a lot more information I could list (and will, if asked), but I wondered if there were ANY legitimate reason for an index's cardinality to suddenly become null while the table is being inserted into.

Answer (score 0):

Your using myisam ? You need to populate it with the command

```
Analyze table yourtable
```

To fill it the only index mysql takes care to generate is the primary key one

Comment: Yes, it's myISAM.  I did an ANALYZE TABLE; I will amend my post to describe what I did to establish the cardinality.

Comment: On seconde thought, I won't: keep getting "an error occurred" when I save my changes.

Answer (score 0):

Cardinality shows as `NULL` after `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS;`

Make sure the keys are enabled! `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS;`